# Windows 7 one minute freeze

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I'm experiencing a very annoying problem on my Windows 7 workstation.
Two or more times per day the computer freezes for more than one minute (with the azure ring cycling), then it works as expected. The CPU utilization during these periods of unavailability is supposed to be low: I'm not asking for heavy computation when the problem occur. 
The computer freezes while I'm executing ordinary activity such as inserting text from keyboard, opening a folder, opening a file or clicking a link in the browser.

There is no record of malfunctioning in the event log. The hard disk seems ok, I had some problem with the integrated nic and disabled it after adding a PCI one.

The workstation is inside a windows domain and folder redirection is active.

The operative system was reinstalled after the first symptoms, but nothing changed.

Do you think it can be due to a nearly faulted hardware ?

How can I investigate the root causes of this problem ? I completely lack adequate tools and ideas...

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: What you describe is a tell-tell sign your HDD is spending a bunch of time trying to access a file and Windows is waiting for that to happen.  **The operative system was reinstalled after the first symptoms, but nothing changed.** - This also means its not a software problem

Comment: Is there a way to have evidence it is really the HDD to slow down the whole system ?

Comment: Sure;  Get yourself a new HDD in order to verify If the problem is the HDD.  Its not going to be any other hardware though.